# Subgroup generated by a set of permutations in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, online-resources

I have a set of $22$ permutations in $S_6$. I want to know does it generates the whole $S_6$. Is there any online tool to compute it?
This is the list.

```
 (1,2,6),
 (1,2,6)(3,4,5),
 (1,3)(2,4,6,5),
 (1,3,2,4,6,5),
 (1,3,6,5)(2,4),
 (1,3)(2,5,6,4),
 (1,3,2,5,4,6),
 (1,3,6,4)(2,5),
 (1,4,2,3)(5,6),
 (1,4,6,5)(2,3),
 (1,4)(2,3,6,5),
 (1,4,6,3)(2,5),
 (1,4)(2,5,6,3),
 (1,4,2,5)(3,6),
 (1,5,2,3)(4,6),
 (1,5,6,4)(2,3),
 (1,5)(2,3,6,4),
 (1,5,6,3)(2,4),
 (1,5)(2,4,6,3),
 (1,5,2,4)(3,6),
 (1,6,2)(3,5,4),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an online tool [here](http://wims.unice.fr/~wims/en_tool~algebra~permgroup.en.phtml). The text box at the bottom allows you to type your generating permutations, each on an individual line, like so:

`(1,2,6)
(1,2,6)(3,4,5)
(1,3)(2,4,6,5)
(1,3,2,4,6,5)
(1,3,6,5)(2,4)
(1,3)(2,5,6,4)
(1,3,2,5,4,6)
(1,3,6,4)(2,5)
(1,4,2,3)(5,6)
(1,4,6,5)(2,3)
(1,4)(2,3,6,5)
(1,4,6,3)(2,5)
(1,4)(2,5,6,3)
(1,4,2,5)(3,6)
(1,5,2,3)(4,6)
(1,5,6,4)(2,3)
(1,5)(2,3,6,4)
(1,5,6,3)(2,4)
(1,5)(2,4,6,3)
(1,5,2,4)(3,6)
(1,6,2)(3,5,4)`

and then press *OK* above the text box. The algorithm then concludes

> The group $G$ is the symmetric group $S_6$ on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Already the three permutations $(1,2,6)$, $(1,2,6)(3,4,5)$, and $(2,5)$ in your set generate all of $S_6$. It is equivalent to show that $(1,2,6)$, $(3,4,5)$, and $(2,5)$ generate $S_6$.

We use repeatedly the [fundamental fact about conjugating permutations](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_Decomposition_of_Conjugate) applied to various permutations already known to be in the subgroup generated by these three elements: "The cycle decomposition of the permutation $\pi\rho\pi^{-1}$ [the conjugation of $\rho$ by $\pi$] can be obtained from that of $\rho$ by replacing each $i$ in the cycle decomposition of $\rho$ with $\pi(i)$."

For example, $(1,2,6)(2,5)(1,2,6)^{-1} = (6,5)$ and then $(1,2,6)(6,5)(1,2,6)^{-1} = (1,5)$ are both in this subgroup. Conjugating these by $(3,4,5)$, we see that every transposition $(a,b)$ where $a\in\{1,2,6\}$ and $b\in\{3,4,5\}$ is in the subgroup.

Now $(1,5)(2,5)(1,5)^{-1} = (2,1)$ and $(6,5)(2,5)(6,5)^{-1} = (2,6)$ are also in the subgroup, and hence so is $(2,1)(2,6)(2,1)^{-1} = (1,6)$; similarly, $(3,4)$ and $(3,5)$ and $(4,5)$ are in the subgroup. Since every transposition has been shown to be in the subgroup generated by $(1,2,6)$, $(3,4,5)$, and $(2,5)$, we see that they generate all of $S_6$.